# How can I get the device subnet-mask on React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to get the subnet-mask of device on android and ios.

I try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-subnet-mask) but it works only for Android.

This is my code:

```
 var getSubnetMask = require("get-subnet-mask")


getSubnetMask.getSubnet((sb) => {
  this.subnet = sb;
});
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was found

Just use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-subnet-mask) package.

Good luck.